# How to identify a SVN path is a directory or file with SVNkit?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

Say you have a specified SVN path like below, How can I know this item is a svn directory or a svn file. thanks.

```
http://cvs-server.test.com:8001/svn/test
```

**Updated**

```
            SVNURL svnUrl = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url);
            SVNRepository repos = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnUrl);
            ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = 
            SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("user1","123");

            repos.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

            SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repos.checkPath(url, repos.getLatestRevision());
```

Why did I get `none` even the url is a file ? I am sure this url exist in SVN. ORZ... There are many bugs with SVNkit .

Comment: You mean: how to identify that a specific folder on your file system is under version control? You have hidden folder called `.svn` in the folders which are under version control. Is that what you mean?

Comment: please review my post . I updated it just now .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String url = "http://cvs-server.test.com:8001/svn/test";
SVNURL svnUrl = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url);
SVNRepository repos = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnUrl);
ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(DEFAULT_USER, DEFAULT_PASS);
repos.setAuthenticationManager(authManager); 
SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repos.checkPath("", repos.getLatestRevision());
```

`nodeKind` will be one of `FILE`, `DIR` or `NONE`.

Comment: why don't you need to specified the username and password ?

Comment: You have to... but that was not your question. I was assuming you know SVNKIT so far.

Comment: Why did I get `none` even the url is a svn file? Is it a bug ?

Comment: Please read the JavaDoc of [SVNNodeKind](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNNodeKind.html)

Comment: I updated post .please review it .thanks. the url exist in svn.

Comment: call `checkPath` with `/test` not with `http://cvs-server.test.com:8001/svn/test` like in my answer mentioned.

Comment: Buddy , It is the same . I got `none`.

Comment: Works but you have a mistake in your code because it needs to be relative path.

It needs to be something like this:

SVNURL svnURL = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url);
  SVNRepository repos = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnURL);

  ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(DEFAULT_USER, DEFAULT_PASS);
  repos.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
  SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repos.checkPath("", repos.getLatestRevision());

Answer (score 3):

If you encounter into bugs, please report them to  http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issues/SVNKIT .

`checkPath` doesn't work with URLs, it works with paths, absolute (i.e. relative to the repository root) or relative (to the URL for which `SVNRepository` instance was constructed) --- see its javadoc for more details

So you can just use this code

```
SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repos.checkPath("", repos.getLatestRevision());
```

or even

```
SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repos.checkPath("", -1);
```

the second variant will be faster because it doesn't perform `getLatestRevision` request, and it's a rather popular way to check the URL existence that is often used in SVNKit itself.

Alternatively you could use an absolute path (which should start with "/") but the path to be specified depends on your repository root. You can get the repository root by running

```
$ svn info "http://cvs-server.test.com:8001/svn/test"
```

or by running

```
repos.getRepositoryRoot(true);
```

from SVNKit code. The absolute path should start with "/" and be relative to the repository root obtained.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
public static boolean isFolder(String url) throws SVNException {
    SVNURL svnURL = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url);
    SVNRepository repos = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(svnURL);
    ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(DEFAULT_USER, DEFAULT_PASS);
    repos.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    SVNNodeKind nodeKind = repos.checkPath("", repos.getLatestRevision());
    System.out.println(nodeKind);
    return nodeKind != null && nodeKind == SVNNodeKind.DIR;
}
```